# Why is let=0 valid but not var=0?

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't

```js
let=0
```

show any syntax errors but

```js
var=0
```

does? (I test it on Safari)

However I tried

```js
console.log(let)
```

but it has errors and seems 'let' is not a already defined variable. Why would that happen?

Comment: because var is defined keyword and let is defined keyword in ES2015 which mostly browser don't support yet, so it allowed you to make a new global variable named as let.

Comment: why would you be trying to assign to javascript keywords? :o

Comment: Good find @MichałPerłakowski.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because `var` has been a keyword forever, but `let` has not. So when adding `let` to the language, the TC39 committee had to specify it such that existing code that used `let` as an identifier didn't break. (One of their prime rules is "don't break the web" and they take it very seriously [thankfully].)

So `let` is a keyword in context, such as a `let` declaration, but can also be an identifier:

```js
let a = 42;                // Keyword, due to context
let = "I'm an identifier"; // Identifier, due to context 
console.log(a);
console.log(let);
```

Note that in strict mode (`"use strict"`), `let` cannot be used as an identifier; the spec that introduced strict mode also reserved `let` and a few other words when used in strict mode (see [ECMAScript 5th edition §7.6.1.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2)), since of course no strict-mode code existed in the wild prior to that spec's adoption, so they could do that. (It *didn't* reserve every single word that's ended up being a keyword since, so sometimes they really have to define things very carefully indeed. For instance, `async` is a perfectly valid identifier even in strict mode, but has special meaning just before `function`.)

```js
"use strict";
let = "I'm an identifier"; // SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
console.log(let);
```

Answer (score 3):

`var` is a reserved word and it can't be a name of a global variable. But `let` also a reserved word. And it differs from the `var` that it can be used as a variable name.

`let` was added in the ES6 version. For compatibility with the older codes, which can have variable name as `let`, it is still correct to use it as a name. `var` was added from the start of Javascript, so why it is disallowed.

```js
let = 0;
console.log(let);
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript has a set of reserved keywords in ES5:

> break, do, instanceof, typeof, case, else, new, var, catch, finally, 
>   return, void, continue, for, switch, while, debugger, function, this,
>   with, default, if, throw, delete, in, try

It’s illegal to use a reserved keyword as a variable or function name in JavaScript. For example following code throws a **SyntaxError** which says `Cannot use the keyword ‘delete’ as a variable name`

```
var delete = 1;
```

But it’s perfectly fine to use ES6 reserved words like let as a variable name in ES5.

```
var let = 1;
```

ES5 defines two `modes` for the language. The regular JavaScript that existed before the introduction of ES5 is considered **`sloppy mode`** and since ES5, JavaScript programmers can choose to write their program in the **`strict mode`**. The strict mode introduces a set of new rules to JavaScript including the additional reserved words. This set of keywords is called **`FutureReservedWord`**. Here is the list:

> implements, interface, let, package, private, protected, public,
>   static, yield

The FutureReservedWord keywords are not enforced in non-strict JavaScript. But in strict mode they are considered reserved words and it’s illegal to use them as variable names.

Read more [here](http://azimi.me/2016/02/11/understanding-strict-mode.html)

So you can use `let` as a variable name if not in **strict mode**. But `var` is a reserved keyword all the time.

So you can do something like

```js
var let = "some thing uneasy!";
console.log(let);
```

But you still can not do

```js
let let = 5;
```

because lexically it is not correct. JS assumes it as multiple declarations and f you are separating your declarations with commas, you should not repeat let. either remove let from each declaration or use semi-colons instead.

Comment: @Glorfindel typo :P fixed!

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered, and just to add to it -

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-keywords), `let` and `static` are not part of keyword list unless *used* in **strict mode**.

> **In strict mode code**, `let` and `static` **are treated as reserved keywords**
>   through static semantic restrictions rather than the lexical grammar.